# AWS Quicksight: showing large text fields using custom insights

Tags: amazon-quicksight

Is there a way to use actions to populate a custom insight with data from a field that is too large to display in a table?

I have two fields of data that includes large amounts of text data, the average number of characters for one of the fields is 1,230. All of my other fields are small enough to show in a table, so I want give the user the ability to click on a link and see this data somehow.

I think I can do this if we take each row in the data and turn it into an html file and then display it in a second analysis, using url parameters to establish the correct url for a custom visual content visual.That all feels a bit hacky and I'm not 100% sure that parameters can be used to populate the URL field of the custom visual content.

Instead I'd like to populate a custom insight visual with the text from the corresponding large fields when a user clicks on a row in the table. In theory I can get the Custom Insight Visual to show the top row based on a value, e.g. a row id but I'm struggling to work out what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured it out.

It takes four steps.

1. Create an action for the table populated with your summary data. Set that action to be a filter action which is activated by a selection. I chose the name "Filter_Table_OnClick".
   [image: Edit Quicksight Action]
2. Create a Custom Insight Visual and add all of the detail fields that you want to display to the "Categories" field well.

[image: Quicksight Categories Field Well]

3. Customise the narrative for your Custom Insight Visual and then add a new "Computation" for each of the fields you want to display in full. Select the "Top Ranked" option and then populate it with the field you want and set the number of records to 1.
   [image: Setting up a computation to display a field]
4. Edit the narrative by using the "insert code" drop down and then add the name of one of your computations, using the relevant code to display the data you want. I used one code to show the field name and a second code to show the value. When you want to show the value you have to add `ComputationName.items[0].categoryValue.value`. You have to follow `items` with the `[0]` as this is the way to indicate to Quicksight that you want the first item in the list. If you use `[1]` it will error. [image: Editing the quicksight narrative]